If $|f(x)-a-bx-cx^2|\to 0$ when $x\to 0$, then $a=f(0), b=f'(0)$ and $c=f''(0)/2$.
Let $f\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)$. I want to prove that if $$\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)-a-bx-cx^2|=0,$$
then $a=f(0)$, $b=f'(0)$ and $c=\frac{f''(0)}{2}$.

Since $$|f(x)-a-bx-cx^2|\leq |bx+cx^2|-|f(x)-a|,$$
we get $$|f(x)-a|\leq |bx+c|+|f(x)-a-bx-cx^2|\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}  0,$$
and thus $a=f(0)$ since $f$ is continuous.

Same, we get $$|f(x)-f(0)-bx|\leq |cx^2|+|f(x)-a-bx-cx^2|\implies \left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-b\right|\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0\implies b=f'(0).$$

Question : How to prove that $$|f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x-cx^2|\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow }0\implies c=\frac{f''(0)}{2}\ \ ?$$



It is not true. We have
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)-a-bx-cx^2| = 0 \\
\iff &\lim_{x\to 0} (f(x)-a-bx-cx^2) = 0 \\
\iff &\lim_{x\to 0} \, (f(x) - a) = 0 \\
\iff & a = f(0) \, .
\end{align}
$$
It does not follow that $b=f'(0)$ or $c=f''(0)/2$. A simple concrete counterexample is $f(x) = x+x^2$ with $a=b=c=0$.

But the following is true: If $f\in C^2(\Bbb R)$ and
$$
 \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-a-bx-cx^2}{x^2} = 0
$$
then $a= f(0)$, $b=f'(0)$, and $c=f''(0)/2$.
First we have
$$ 
0 = \lim_{x\to 0} x^2 \frac{f(x)-a-bx-cx^2}{x^2}
= \lim_{x\to 0} (f(x)-a-bx-cx^2) = f(0) - a 
$$
which implies $f(0) =a$, then
$$
0 = \lim_{x\to 0} x \frac{f(x)-f(0)-bx-cx^2}{x^2}
= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)-bx-cx^2}{x} = f'(0) -b
$$
which implies $f'(0) = b$, and finally, using L'Hospital's rule twice,
$$
0 = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-a - bx-cx^2}{x^2}
= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x) - b-2cx}{2x}
= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f''(x) - 2c}{2} = \frac{f''(0)-2c}{2}
$$
so that $c=f''(0)/2$. L'Hospital's rule can be applied because it is given that the limit on the right exists.
